# How to get a dynamic value from a post and use it to get to a specific function in Django

Tags: django, forms, post

I'm trying to accomplish this.

Though this function:
`my_site/inter_page_composition` (that renders `mysite/inter_page.html`) I'm proposing a form where I get three values: `start_date`, `end_date` and the specific function that computes and render the specific graphic. This function is where we'll land afterwards (for ex. graphic1, graphic2 and so on).
So, in the `forms.py` I put this:

```
    from django import forms
    from django.forms.widgets import NumberInput    
    
    class formGraphicChoice(forms.Form):
            start_date = forms.DateField(
                widget=NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','type':'date'}),required=True,
                label = "Starting Date"
            )
            end_date = forms.DateField(
                widget=NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','type':'date'}),required=True,
                label = "End Date"
            )
            selectedGraph = (('gra1', 'Label of graphic 1'),
                             ('gra2', 'Label of graphic 2'),
                             ('gra3', 'Label of graphic 3'),
                             )
            Graphfields = forms.ChoiceField(choices=selectedGraph,label = "Choose the graphic")
```

Then, in the `mysite/inter_page.html`, specifically in the `{% block content %}` part, I placed the following:

```
{% block content %}
    <div id="content" class="content">
      <!-- begin page-header -->
      <h1 class="page-header">Graphic choice page<small></small></h1>
      <!-- end page-header -->
      <!-- begin row -->
      <div class="row">
          <!-- begin col-xl-12  -->
          <div class="col-xl-12 ui-sortable">
              <!-- begin panel -->
              <div class="panel panel-inverse" data-sortable-id="form-stuff-12">
                  <!-- begin panel-heading -->
                  <div class="panel-heading ui-sortable-handle">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">Parameters<h4>
                  </div>
                  <!-- end panel-heading -->
                  <section class="panel-body bg-black-transparent-5">
                  <!-- <section class="col-6 col-12-narrower feature">-->
                    <form action="{% url 'page_choice' %}" method="post" class="margin-bottom-0" >
                          {% csrf_token %}
                          <br>
                          {{ form | crispy }}
                          <br>
                          <br>
                          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Show it"> 
                      </form>
                      <br>
                      <br>
                  </section>
              </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Finally, my view is the following:

```
import json
from urllib import request
from django.shortcuts import render
import logging
from import_data.models import MetaData, Province
import datetime
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators  import  staff_member_required
from .forms import formGraphicChoice
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def inter_page_composition(request):
    form = formGraphicChoice()
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "inter_page/inter_page.html", context)

def page_choice(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = formGraphicChoice(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.cleaned_data['Graphfields'] == 'gra1':
                create_graphics1_logic(form)
            else:
                create_graphics2_logic(form)

def create_graphics1_logic(form):
    form = formGraphicChoice(request.POST)
    start_date = form.cleaned_data["start_date"]         
    end_date = form.cleaned_data["end_date"] 
    context = {}
    context["data_start"] = start_date 
    context["data_stop"] = end_date 
    ...
    logic for the graph
    ...
    return render(request, "inter_page/gra1.html", context)
```

So, I get the error:

> AttributeError at /page_choice 'formGraphicChoice' object has no
> attribute 'user'

here:

line 28, in page_choice
create_graphics1_logic(form) …
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
form

request
<WSGIRequest: POST '/page_choice'>

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem lays somewhere in your form. I suppose you are trying to access the actual user of the session inside of your form? Usually user related stuff gets passed to the form on creation from your view. Would be helpful to see your form.

Comment: Did you really provide the entire form with all fields, all methods, everything? Also is the function `inter_page_composition` complete? Or did you just provide a snippet?

Comment: I've rewritten the entire question and provided the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are choosing the wrong approach. The user selects what type of Graph he wants to see. Let's say he decides for graphic2.

```html
<form action="{% url 'app/to_view' %}" method="post" class="margin-bottom-0" >
     {% csrf_token %}
     <br>
     {{ form | crispy }}
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Show it"> 
</form>
```

This form then leads django on submit to your view. Then my personal choice would be to let the view handle that logic what graphic to display

```py
def display_view(request):
    [..]
    if form.cleaned_data['Graphfields'] == 'graphics1':
        graph = create_graphics1_logic()
    elif form.cleaned_data['Graphfields'] == 'graphics2':
        graph = create_graphics2_logic()
    else:
        graph = create_graphics3_logic()
```

I know this does not answer your question directly, but passing different urls to the action parameter is far more difficult.

#### Edit

Try to avoid passing the entire view logic to another function. It certainly is possible, but then you also have to pass request and everything. Try to keep it simple.

```py
def page_choice(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = formGraphicChoice(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            start_date = form.cleaned_data["start_date"]         
            end_date = form.cleaned_data["end_date"]
            if form.cleaned_data['Graphfields'] == 'gra1':
                graph = create_graphics1_logic(start_date, end_date)
                template = "inter_page/gra1.html"
            else:
                graph = create_graphics2_logic(start_date, end_date)
                template = "inter_page/gra2.html"
            context = {"graph": graph}
            return render(request, template, context)
    else:
        # handle the case when someone goes to this url with get request
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(["GET"])

def create_graphics1_logic(start_date, end_date):
    # create logic that only creates and returns graph
    return graph
```

Comment: I appreciate a lot this change of perspective, and I've tried to implement it. Nonetheless, there is still something that I've missed. I tried to resume it by editing the principal message. Thanks for any additional hint!